# .NET Core 2.0 Build not including dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-core, build

When I build my .NET Core 2.0 console app, I move it over to the server and I then try and run it. I am getting the error "An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest..."

I add the dlls to the local folder that it is searching for, but it ends up still needing system dlls like Data.SqlClient.

How do I build the project where it includes all the dependencies in the output files? I've published the project with Visual Studio 2017, however, it still says things are missing when I copy all those files over. I've tried building and publishing with VSCode and have the same problem.

Comment: In Visual Studio, right click the references and choose Properties. Is Copy Local set to true? If not, set it to true and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. When I deployed my application in host environment and executed with dotnet command like "dotnet myapp.dll" it worked fine using the host environment's .NET Core runtime. 
But when I packaged the same application as a Standalone application with an .exe file included to start the application, I faced this error for Newtonsoft.json Nuget Package when .exe file is executed.
My observation is as below, and I was able to solve the problem accordingly.

**Framework-dependent deployment:**
If the application uses third-party libraries and intention is to use the .NET Core runtime in the host environment, then the checkbox in the "Manage Packages for Solution" has to be checked in the Nuget Package Manager (as shown in the screenshot).

[image]


**Self-contained deployment:** 
If the published application is supposed to be a stand alone application in the host environment (even with an .exe file), then the application's .csproj file should include the RuntimeIdentifiers [(.NET Core RIDs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) specified. Also the third party libraries have to be included in PackageReference. For example,

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs

Comment: That check box (in the first screenshot) has does not relate to any persistent state: It's just for choosing which projects to install or uninstall in.

Answer (score -2):

You need to publish the application to have all the dependencies included

Comment: The OP specifically said that the project was published with VS 2017.